# Ubuntu black screen Separate SSD

Tags: boot, 16.04, drivers, nvidia, ssd

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my desktop on a separate SSD from my Windows installation. So, basically, a fresh install but I am having some compiling issues:

1. The video card, I believe, is incompatible after doing some reading.
2. I have installed Ubuntu on the SSD already so I can't get into it without the screen going black.
3. I am trying to download the drivers through the "try Ubuntu" option but I can't get a network connection probably because I don't have the drivers for my network stick.

How do I get the correct drivers for the proper SSD install?

Comment: What video card?  Have you tried options like "nomodeset"?   What network driver do you need and what network hardware do you have?

Comment: I have tried nomodeset, It allowed me to get into the try ubuntu via the usb, however, booting into the ssd It doesnt give me a grub menu to do it from. Just boots straight in and goes to a black screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force the grub screen to appear when booting the install, try holding down a key like shift or tab after powering on.

Once you get to the grub screen, type "e" to edit (instructions at bottom of the screen) and add the "nomodeset" word in place of the "splash quiet" words on the line starting with "linux". Then control X to boot.

The first thing to do is add the proprietary video drivers so you can boot without the nomodeset. Run "Software Updater" select the Settings button, and the Additional Drivers tab to select a driver. If you have wireless problems too, maybe use an ethernet cable until you get the video fixed.